# Developer story bug: top x%

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

Noticed a difference between the developer story and the regular CV:

Old CV:

[image]

Developer story:

[image]

Shouldn't these numbers match as they are using the same data?

Comment: Impostor syndrome, eh?

Comment: ummm, no... not really ;)

Comment: I've posted a follow-up: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321858/what-is-a-top-1-user-in-a-tag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We know that the percentages are not the same.

The algorithm is still being debated internally, but the careers one was simply never correct in the Stack Overflow context. It *only* ever counted between users on Careers.

The percentages you see in your dev story, are obtained by accounting for *all* users ever active in that tag on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The Developer Story now uses the criteria that I suggested in [What is a top 1% user in a tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321858/what-is-a-top-1-user-in-a-tag) and that seem to portrait things more realistically than both the old CV and the initial Developer Story criteria. See that post for more details.