# Top N% on Developer CV

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

It would be nice to have "higher" tag percentile categories other than the standard 10% and 20%.

[image]

For people who are in the top 1% it should say "Top 1%". Who's with me?

Comment: Maybe for top 1% but not too many!

Comment: Perhaps it should the best two of 1, 5, 10, 20

Comment: Be careful what you ask for.  There are not actually that many companies that only hire "the best".  In general they window-shop for 3-5 years of experience and cheap.  You've only got one shot at making a good first impression, if you can't get your foot in the door then you'll never get in.

Comment: @HansPassant hmm you have a point there. Maybe it's better the way it is. Addtionally, "the best" is not necessrily reflected by a high tag score on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will be pleased to hear, that this is exactly what we've been doing. If you want to take it for a spin sign up for the [developer-story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/developer-story) [beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319524/the-developer-story-private-beta-has-started).

[Developer story bug: top x%](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320060/developer-story-bug-top-x)

Comment: Cool have done so. Looking forward to getting my invite!