# What is a top 1% user in a tag?

Tags: discussion, developer-story

**Update:** The criteria described here have now been implemented in the Developer Story.

---

Just like the classic Careers CV, the Developer Story can show "Top X%" percentiles that show where a user is in respect other Stack Overflow users in a particular tag:

[image: Screenshot of the top tag percentile section in a Developer Story with the tooltip "This user is part of the top 1% Stack Overflow answerers on those technologies"]

The old CV calculated those numbers with respect to all *Careers users*. In other words, "Top 20% for jQuery" means *among people who are active in the jQuery tag and have a CV*, you're among the top fifth.

Now that the Developer Story is on Stack Overflow, we started calculating the percentiles with respect to *all* Stack Overflow users active in the tag.

This caused a pretty [big change in the values](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320060/developer-story-bug-top-x), because the number of users we compare you to is much larger, with a long tail of users who may just have very few answers (or none at all, because right now we compare you to everyone who has ever answered *or asked* a question in the tag).

Now, the CV numbers always seemed too unfavorable; comparing you to the rather arbitrary group of people who have a CV does not seem appropriate for a number that's supposed to showcase that your *Stack Overflow* activity in a particular tag is noteworthy.

On the other hand, the new numbers certainly seem inflationary, so we think that the good values are somewhere in between.

So the question is, who is a top 10% contributor to the Ruby tag? What does it mean to be more prolific in PHP than 99% of the other contributors? Or, using the words of the tooltip, what is a "Stack Overflow answerer on C#"?

Let's look at data. The following is a pretty typical graph (in this case it's the one for the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag, but it looks similar for other tags) that shows the number of users that have a certain amount of answers in the tag.

[image: A histogram of Stack Overflow users by their number of Android answers; notworthy details are described in the next paragraph.]

So 105k users have one Android answer, 27k have two, etc. As you can see, there's a sharp drop-off between 1 and 2, but the subsequent cliffs aren't as steep by far. So there's a huge amount of users with one answer (drive-by answers? only-ever answers? answers where the question happened to have the tag but the topic was mostly about something else?), but starting at 2 it looks much more normal.

This makes me think that we should consider a user a contributor to the tag, an "answerer", if they have posted at least two answers.

I have created a [test page](http://thingadongdong.com/s/percentile/) where you can enter a Stack Overflow user's profile URL, and that shows the top X% values under the CV logic, the current Developer Story logic, and my suggested new logic.

Please try it out by entering your (or someone else's) profile URL, check whether you feel that the new logic seems to fairly evaulate the user(s), and post any thoughts you have as answers here.

Thanks!

Comment: Just of curiosity - does that graph show that no one has answered 30 or more android questions or is it just the scaling?

Comment: @JonClements No, I just cut it off at 30.

Comment: Doesn't make a lot of difference, except that a [tag] that covers a subject I deal with every day in my paid job now falls in the 5% bracket.  Chronic problem btw, what I like to do in my free time just doesn't intersect that well with what companies like to pay me a salary to do.  So, roughly, you are just displaying bad data that doesn't help me get the right job at all :)

Comment: @HansPassant These numbers showcase *Stack Overflow* activity, which admittedly doesn't have to translate 100% to what you actually do on your job. I don't think it's "bad data" as long as it's not interpreted incorrectly. The tags you *work* with are something that you can set yourself in the CV or Developer Story, and that's what's actually used when matching users to jobs.

Comment: @HansPassant Also note that the CV doesn't even have 1% and 5% buckets, so compared to what employers see today, the new logic is a step up for you. Now, if you think that your Stack Overflow activity in that tag should be putting you into the top 1% of users in that tag, that would be something to talk about.

Comment: The test page is missing out a `<title>` tag. :|

Comment: @BhargavRao Oh the horror!

Comment: Yep, You have a habit of forgetting that, Am I right? ;)

Comment: Just for clarity, the comparison is done on reputation, right? Take all answerers, get their reputation in that tag, and calculate the quantile of answerer X's rep..?

Comment: @mvai Almost; it's the sum of answer scores, the same number that's on the [tags tab of your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4288782/m-vai?tab=tags) (e.g. 411 for [tag:android] in your case).

Comment: A more elegant solution than stripping `answers < 2` from the distribution could be stripping `answer score == 0`. I would rather exclude a guy with 30 answers but no upvotes, than someone with a single great answer. I can't imagine how the values would be shifted though.

Comment: I must say the new DS logic works better for me. Some 1% tags seem quite nonsense... Top 1% in resize?!

Comment: @mvai Arguably somebody with 30 answers in a particular tag -- no matter the score -- should be considered an answerer in that tag, if not a particularly successful one.

Comment: @Burkhard Yeah, some of the tags that end up there are [pretty nonsensical](https://twitter.com/balpha/status/382398118894923776) for showcasing in such a way. That's why you can always choose which ones to actually display.

Comment: @mvai: I have a few 'lucky hit' answers in tags I don't often post in. And in other tags where I try to make an effort to contribute but the voting is slower (less popular tag), the one-hit-wonders with a high score do stand out like a sore thumb; 9 out of 10 cases they wrote an answer to a question only tangentially related to that tag. So I prefer the current choice, myself. Even though my one-hit-wonder answer in the `floating-point` tag still earns me a top-5% mention (I obviously have answered more fp questions than just the highly-voted one).

Comment: @balpha I agree but I think the same of single-answerers. Among the three options in the test site, I agree with your suggestion, it just doesn't seem very justified to me. Cutting on `answer score` sounds better to my ears, meaning that we acknowledge there's a loose tail in the distribution, so we cut part of it to give realistic indicators.

Comment: Same result for me as @Burkhard where the new logic yields a much better match with reality, eliminating a bunch of oddball 1% tags.

Comment: @JohnnyHK me too. I'm getting top %1 for for-loop with current logic. That's... something I certainly wouldn't want myself to be described by my profile. It's nowhere near my top tags.

Comment: @balpha: "*Thanks!*" Really?!  I suggest you add greetings e.g. "Dear my friend madam/sir," at the top of your post ;-)

Comment: Also, I suggest giving the y axis a logarithmic scale. That will reveal trends more clearly on this type of distribution.

Comment: Yes, I'd definitely agree that I'm _not_ top 1% in [html] so I agree it seems to be somewhat inflated, although top 5% seems _a bit_ more realistic. In fact, I'm not even a regaular answerer in [html] - it seems that having one fairly highly voted answer distorts it significantly (?). Perhaps it should weight answer count more the overall score ?

Comment: What happens to the graph if you remove 0 rep users?

Comment: I tried you updated algo on myself and I think it is a truer picture of what is going on.  I would not say I am in the top 1% in [tag:multithreading] but the current CV tag % calc says I am.

Comment: I don't particularly like the suggestion floating around to base it on answer score due to the fact that it unfairly weighs in the direction of answers to dupes/poorly researched questions that often receive quick answers that get heavily upvoted... I'd rather just stick to the >=2. There are many good answers that just don't receive votes due to the question being uninteresting.

Comment: Current DS put me in top 5% for C++ and Python. Proposed puts me in 20%. I'd say I shouldn't even be there with the volume of my answers / rep.

Comment: Either way, I find it amusing I'm in the top percentiles for exciting technologies like `file`, `arrays`, and `class`

Comment: Is "the top 1000 most popular tags on Stack Overflow" part of the proposed logic or a limitation of the test page?

Comment: @BenVoigt The latter. The actual logic uses the top 5000. I'd like to improve that as well -- there have been multiple mentions of the "nonsensical tags" like [tag:if-statement], i.e. tags that don't really lend themselves to this kind of things. And at the [bottom of the top 5000](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=139&tab=popular), there's a lot of those tags. But I have no immediate plans to change that.

Comment: @null: Users start with a score of 1, so probably... nothing?

Comment: What happens to the graph if you remove 1 rep users?

Comment: My profile entered in your test returned a blank page. Pretty happy to be in the top 2% for this week's reputation though

Comment: The new logic looks more realistic on my profile. The current logic puts me in the top 1% for `regex` and I don't even have a bronze badge in it yet.

Comment: Add a bottom X% for us more noob levels!

Comment: Looks like mine was blank, does that mean I'm 0%? ha

Comment: Will you adjust the algorithm on the old CV to match the Developer Story ones?