# Why discrepancy of numbers in % rank per tag

Tags: discussion, support

When I look at my [developer CV](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/niklas) it ranks me top 10 % in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and top 10 % in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). But when I look by an [actual query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50844/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag) I'm ranked top 5 % in C and top 4 % in python. Is that because the calculations are different, maybe tag synonyms and tag subcategories count in the former query but not the latter?

Update: The data query now reports that I'm top 4 % in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) but on my [cv](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/niklas) it says top 10 % in C. Should the CV get updated?

Comment: Pretty sure they use 1%, 5%, 10%, ...

Comment: @NathanOliver But why does it say 10 % in C when I am top 4 %?

Comment: Could it be that the developer CV takes questions and answers into account? The SEDE query only looks at your answers.

Comment: Yeah, just ran it for myself and the Dev CV ranks me at `top 5%` for `PHP` & `XML` but the query ranks me at `2%` and `3%` respectively.

Comment: Related: [What is a top 1% user in a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321858/what-is-a-top-1-user-in-a-tag?rq=1)