# How does "TOP 10%" work in the Developer Story?

Tags: support, tags, developer-story

In my Developer Story, I'm currently in the top 10% of the AngularJS tag, and before that I was in the top 20%.

I checked my percentile for other tags with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50844/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag) and apparently I'm in the top 20% of the Angular-Material tag, but I can't display it in my Developer Story.

So, I was wondering, what are the conditions in order to display that one is in the top 1, 5, 10 or 20% of a specific tag?

Comment: @HansPassant Yes but there is also a top 20%. Before I was able to show that I was in the top 20% of the AngularJS tag. Look at [his developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/7201256) by example, he is in the top 20% of Android

Comment: Maybe there is a minimum score threshold?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much consistency; query shows I am it top 1% and 3% for `keras` and `scikit-learn` respectively, but in my dev story they show up as 5% and 10% respectively...

Comment: @desertnaut, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321858/what-is-a-top-1-user-in-a-tag